# How to use multitouch behaviour from multitouch.codeplex.com

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I want to pinch zoom in images in a Windows Phone 7.1 app. Here are the steps that I have followed -

Downloaded the latest binaries.
Added System.Windows.Interactivity.dll and MultiTouch.Behaviors.Silverlight.WP71.dll to project from WP71/Release folder.
Added reference in XAML:

```
xmlns:mt="clr-namespace:MultiTouch.Behaviors.Silverlight4;assembly=MultiTouch.Behaviors.Silverlight.WP71"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Here is my code:

```
<Image Source="pic.jpg">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <mt:MultiTouchBehavior IsTranslateEnabled="True"
                                       IsRotateEnabled="False" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
```

I'm getting this error on running the app:

> The type 'MultiTouchBehavior' was not found.

Comment: Weird, I did the exact same thing and it works fine on WP7.1. Does the sample project provided in the downloaded zip work ?

Comment: @AlaaMasoud Strange! I tried running the sample project and it works perfectly. I guess they messed up while uploading the binaries. :/

Comment: Try building the library projects and reference their output instead.